# Could not load the assembly 'App_Web_xxxxxxxxx' . Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page

Tags: asp.net, hosting

I publish my asp.net project and i hosted it into server using FileZilla Software.When i check the url it shows me the error like **Could not load the assembly 'App_Web_xxxxxxxxx' . Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page**.I tried to solve this issue by deleting bin folder,changing

"`<%@ page title="Myproject" language="C#" masterpagefile="~/MySite.master" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="_Default, App_Web_dlpovpf5" %>`"

Code(When i googled i  got this things).but i cant get perfect answer to solve this issue.So anybody can help me to solve this.

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a permission issue. I gave modify permission for that particular domain user and write permission for " network service " to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is the your application pool in IIS that is pointing to other framework version. So create a new application pool and set the correct version .net framework version i.e 2.0 and assign that application pool to your web site.

For more info- See following link.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1f776659-da2e-4922-9f95-c6f648fa836e/could-not-load-the-assembly-xxx-make-sure-that-it-is-compiled-before-accessing-the-page?forum=asmxandxml

That is having similar kind of issue.

Comment: i done my project in version 4.0.so i need to reconstruct my project in version 2.0

Comment: that's what just an example. Make sure that you have correct .net framework version in application pool. if you are using .net framework 4.0 then your application pool should have 4.0

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when I forget to convert my site to an applications.

[image]

You need to create an application if you are writing a .NET app, otherwise it will not compile.

I now create set my app before publishing so I don't forget `:-S`